# What is the idiom for "throne always succeed by their sons only"?

Tags: idiom-requests

What is the idiom for "throne always succeed by their sons only"?

What i means is: there is no chance for new talents.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Your question is lacking in info. Could you elaborate more on what you mean, with more examples and research that you may have done?

Comment: Is this already an idiom in your first language? Can you give more detail about this?

Comment: Turning it on it's ear:  The acorn doesn't fall very far from the tree.

Comment: There’s my newly coined. “*If you don’t have an in, you’re out.*”  don’t know if anyone has said this before, it’d be astounding if they hadn’t but who knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common idiom is **'It's a closed shop.'**

Although this applies in the first instance to trades unions and working practices, the expression is used far more broadly to describe a situation involving nepotism, elitism, selectivism and the like.

Such an example is this one from [the Irish Times](http://www.irishtimes.com/sport/other-sports/it-s-a-lock-in-for-vintners-only-with-midweek-extravaganza-on-lough-mask-in-co-mayo-1.1934935):

> "IT MAY not be the largest trout competition but it’s up there with
>   the best,” a sentiment echoed time and time again at last week’s
>   vintner’s fly-fishing championship on Lough Mask in Co Mayo. While
>   the world cup competition sets claim to the greatest number of anglers
>   (460 this year), the vintners is an absolute gem. It’s a closed shop,
>   by invite only. “There are 50 or 60 on the waiting list,” according to
>   organiser Tom “Swanky” Sweeney.

And one from the [IMDb message board](http://messageboard.donedealpro.com/boards/archive/index.php/t-53428.html):

> The reality of getting a script from paper to screen is a gigantic
>   step for known writers let alone unknown ones.
>
> Hollywood is virtually a closed shop.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider, ***blood is thicker than water***

> Blood is thicker than water. and Blood runs thicker than water.
>
> *Prov.* People who are related have stronger obligations to each other than to people outside the family.
>
> [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Blood+is+thicker+than+water)

Answer (score 0):

You may be thinking of an **oligarchy**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oligarchy

It generally refers to a small group of people, but there's no reason that small group couldn't be a family.